# Same anonymous firebase user across all local browsers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to get the same firebase anonymous user across all browsers on the same pc?

In my site the user can sign in anonymously and that creates a firebase user with a unique firebase.UID but the thing is that if he tries to sign in to another browser that creates another user(that is the expected functionality) but I want somehow to tell firefox that this user that is about to be created is the same as the user that got created in chrome.

One more thing is that the user can receive push notifications, if the user wants them that produces a messaging token that I can use to push a notification. Is there any way to also have the same msg-token and push at both of the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to transfer a Firebase Authentication anonymous user from one app/browser instance to another. You'll have to ask the user to upgrade in their initial browser window.

Comment: Hmmm... after posting this, I started doubting myself. Hold on while I double-check...

Comment: One thought that came to my mind was to somehow transfer cookies but I dont know if its possible. Another idea was to create flash cookies in order to be seen by all browsers but flash is out of the question. And a final idea was to find a unique pc identifier and check if a "new" uid is under that identifier then that means that those UIDs are the same. But still Im in the dark on how I should approach this.

Comment: I'm mostly looking at whether it is possible to use the JWT token (that identifies the Firebase user) from one browser instance in another browser instance. If it is possible, you will have to find a way to securely transfer it. But I'll be honest, this sounds way more complex than I typically like dealing with. Any mistake in there and your authentication is suddenly not secure anymore.

Comment: So if you needed the 'chrome anonymous user' to be the same with 'firefox anonymous user', how would you tackle that?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd ask the user to sign in.

Comment: oh well unfortunately I want to make it with anonymous log in, but really thanks for your time mate!!